# how to copy files in gradle without explicitly specify task name in the command line(gradle build copy)

Tags: gradle, build.gradle

When I type "gradle build", it runs the build task from java plugin.
Can I make a copy task as the part of build task? because I dont want to run the command like this "gradle build copy"

Comment: What is it that you want to copy, and to where? Resources are automatically copied, so depending on what you want, you might not need to do anything other than make sure the files live in the right original locaiton.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by adding a task dependency. For example:

```
build.dependsOn(copy)
```

You can learn more about Gradle in the [Gradle User Guide](http://gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/userguide_single.html) and the many sample builds that come with the full Gradle distribution.